# JQGrid, Dropdown not added defaul value

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, jqgrid

Dropdown ignors the adding of a default row to list

.CS

```
private const string DropDownListValue = "[All]";
private const string DropDownListText = "[All]";

 private void LoadProduct()
    {
        try
        {
            FieldGoalEntities objEntity = new FieldGoalEntities();

            IQueryable<Product> objProduct = from p in objEntity.Product
                                             select p;

            ddlProduct.Items.Clear();

            if (objProduct != null)
            {

                ddlProduct.DataSource = objProduct;
                ddlProduct.DataValueField = "ProductCode";
                ddlProduct.DataTextField = "ProductCode";
                ddlProduct.DataBind();
            }

            ddlProduct.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(DropDownListText, DropDownListValue));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Common.LogEvent(Common.LoggingType.Error, "LoadProduct", ex.Message);
            Common.ShowMessageBox(this.Master, "Error", "Load Product Status: " +     ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

//ASPX

//DropdownBox

I need the all added for the filtering, but for some reason if I do the databinding in the .CS file it leaves out the [ALL]

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (CheckEmployee())
            {
                if (gvSaleView.AjaxCallBackMode == AjaxCallBackMode.None)
                {
                 
                    LoadProduct();

                }
            }
        }

        InitializeGridSettings();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should call `ddlProduct.DataBind();` after you've added All to the `Items` list

```
if (objProduct != null)
{

    ddlProduct.DataSource = objProduct;
    ddlProduct.DataValueField = "ProductCode";
    ddlProduct.DataTextField = "ProductCode";

}

ddlProduct.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(DropDownListText, DropDownListValue));
ddlProduct.DataBind();
```